# How to manipulate dictionary with tuple keys to output pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Say I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
{('a','1'):2,
 ('a','2'):1,
 ('b','1'):3,
 ('b','2'):2}
```

I want to get a dataframe result that takes the highest value item for the first key ('a','b' in this case) and create a dataframe from the tuple key.

```
key    value
'a'      '1'
'b'      '1'
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: What do you mean by take the "highest frequency key pair"? Is the value in the dictionary the frequency?

Comment: yes, highest frequency refers to the value in the dictionary. for key value pair starting with 'a', highest frequency is 2; for 'b', 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# let d is your dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(d.keys(),columns=['key','value'])
df['freq'] = pd.DataFrame(d.values())
df['freq'] = pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()))
df = df.loc[df[['key','freq']].groupby('key').idxmax().freq]
       .drop('freq',axis=1)

Out[]:
    key value
2   a   1
0   b   1
```

Reset the index if you want:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

Out[]:
    key value
0   a   1
1   b   1
```